# Padding between divs and vertical scrollbar or vertial scrolling div

Tags: css

Trying to see if this is even doable. Got a vertically scrolling div designed to display a series of div's as a timeline. That all works. However, I'n trying to see if there's a way to adding some padding between the divs in the container and the vertical scrollbar itself.

Right now, each div has both a left and bottom black border. Then the scrollbar which is grey and black. So that scrollbar appears to be too close to the divs.

Here's my current code if anyone can help (if this is even doable):

```css
html {
   scrollbar-width: auto;
   scrollbar-color:#ee4135 #757575;
}
.timeline{
    background:#ebebeb;
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:3rem 0 1.5rem;
    position:relative;
}
.timeline-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    height:260px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    scrollbar-color:#000000 #cecece;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.timeline-item{
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    min-width:460px;
    width:460px;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div class="timeline">
        <div class="timeline-wrapper">
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide One</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Two</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Three</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Four</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Five</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Six</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Seven</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Eight</p></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but, have you tried using `gap`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add padding-bottom:

```css
html {
   scrollbar-width: auto;
   scrollbar-color:#ee4135 #757575;
}
.timeline{
    background:#ebebeb;
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:3rem 0 1.5rem;
    position:relative;
}
.timeline-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    height:260px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    scrollbar-color:#000000 #cecece;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.timeline-item{
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    min-width:460px;
    width:460px;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div class="timeline">
        <div class="timeline-wrapper">
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide One</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Two</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Three</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Four</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Five</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Six</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Seven</p></div>
          <div class="timeline-item" itemscope><p>Slide Eight</p></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```